# How Can I Extend The UserController in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, spree

According to the Spree Guide, one can add users_controller_decorator.rb to the controllers folder to extend the UsersController functionality.

I added

```
Spree::UsersController.class_eval do
   before_filter :load_stock_locations
   def load_stock_locations
       @stock_locations = Spree::StockLocation.all
   end
end
```

However, when I try to access @stock_locations in the /app/views/spree/admin/users/_form.html.erb , it is nil.

Could someone help explain why I can't access this variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden `Spree::UsersController` which basically contains request and response methods at front-end(end user) side.

instead, try overriding backend users controller which is 'Spree::Admin::UsersController' and apply the same logic.

you can find the spree's admin user controller here https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/users_controller.rb

Comment: thanks, I got it to work by creating a spree/admin/user_controller.rb file in controllers and overriding Spree::Admin::UsersController by copying over the file and making my changes!

(using class_eval doesn't seem to trigger the before_filter!!!!)

Thanks!!!